# How can the symbols be bigger than each other? Or do I not understand something? Could you explain what this code does?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is it ok to compare symbols with each other?

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;// For Example, Why if "k = 4" it outputs "r o" ? //
int main() {
    char word[] = "programming";
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        if (word[i] > word[i + 1]) {
            cout << word[i] << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can compare characters - `char` is an integer type.

Comment: @paddy I think the question means "_character_" instead of "_symbol_" and is asking what `>` on characters means.

Comment: You are not comparing characters, you are comparing integer values that represent characters according to current encoding, such as ASCII.

Comment: Thanks, But how can I find out which character is bigger? For Example, Why `(word[i] > word[i + 1])` here we have 'r' bigger than 'o' ? Sorry for my English (

Comment: because most encodings assign numbers to letters in alphabetical order.

Comment: You can find a list of the ASCII encoding, which is almost always used, for example [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html). For example the letter `'p'` corresponds to the value of `112` and the letter `'r'` corresponds to `114`. So the expression `'p' > 'r'` evaluates to boolean false.

Comment: And "alphabetical order" usually means "in the order of the English alphabet; other orders and non-English characters are just silly ideas by foreigners".

Comment: Thank you all for such a quick response, this is my very first question on this forum, and I am very surprised by the speed of reaction))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `char` data type is an **integral type**, meaning the underlying value is stored as an **integer**. Moreover, the integer stored by a `char` variable is ***intepreted*** as an [ASCII character](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/%7Etway/resources/ascii-table.html).

ASCII specifies a way to map english characters(and some other few symbols) to numbers between `0` and `127`. That is, each english character(and some other few symbols) has a corresponding number between `0` and `127`. This number is formally called a **code point**.

For example, the code point for the english character `a` is `97`. Similarly, the code point for the english character `H` is `72`. You can find the list of code points for all the characters [here](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/%7Etway/resources/ascii-table.html).

The important thing to note here is that the underlying value of a `char` variable is stored as an integer. Lets take some examples to clarify this,

```
char var1 = 'a'; //here var1 is stored as the integer 97 
char var2 = 'H'; //here var2 is stored as the integer 72
```

In the above snippet, `var1` is stored as the integer `97` because the code point for the english character `a` is `97`. Similarly, `var2` is stored as the integer `72` because the english character `H` corresponds to the code point `72`.

---

Now lets come back to your original question. In particular **what happens when `k =4`**.

For `k = 4`, the `for` loop will be executed `4` times.

**Iteration 0**: Here `i = 0`

The `if` block basically translates to:

```
if (word[0] > word[0 + 1]) {
            cout << word[0] << endl;
        }
```

which is:

```
if ('p' > 'r') {
            cout << 'p' << endl;
        }
```

which is(using the ascii table):

```
if (112 > 114) {
            cout << 'p' << endl;
        }
```

since the condition inside `if` is `false`, the body of the `if` block will not be executed and you'll get no output.

**Iteration 1:** Here `i = 1`

The `if` block basically translates to:

```
if (word[1] > word[1 + 1]) {
            cout << word[1] << endl;
        }
```

which is:

```
if ('r' > 'o') {
            cout << 'r' << endl;
        }
```

which is(using the ascii table):

```
if (114 > 111) {
            cout << 'r' << endl;
        }
```

since the condition inside `if` is `true`, the body of the `if` block will be executed and you'll get `r` as output(which is followed by a newline).

**Iteration 2:** Here `i = 2`

The `if` block basically translates to:

```
if (word[2] > word[2 + 1]) {
            cout << word[2] << endl;
        }
```

which is:

```
if ('o' > 'g') {
            cout << 'o' << endl;
        }
```

which is(using the ascii table):

```
if (111 > 103) {
            cout << 'o' << endl;
        }
```

since the condition inside `if` is `true`, the body of the `if` block will be executed and you'll get `o` as output(which is followed by a newline).

**Iteration 3:** Here `i = 3`

The `if` block basically translates to:

```
if (word[3] > word[3 + 1]) {
            cout << word[3] << endl;
        }
```

which is:

```
if ('g' > 'r') {
            cout << 'g' << endl;
        }
```

which is(using the ascii table):

```
if (103 > 114) {
            cout << 'g' << endl;
        }
```

since the condition inside `if` is `false`, the body of the `if` block will not be executed and you'll get no output.

Hence you get the output:

```
r
o
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to compare symbols with each other?

Yes, it is OK.

> Why if "k = 4" it outputs "r o" ?

Character types are integers. Each integer value of the character type is mapped to a symbol<sup>1</sup>. This mapping is called a character set or character encoding.

In the character encoding of the system where you ran the program, the value of the character that maps to the symbol 'r' has a greater value than the character that maps to the symbol 'o', while that 'o' character has smaller value than the character that maps to 'g'.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a simplification. There are special non-printable charcters such as null terminator which aren't symbols as such. Furthermore, the mapping isn't so simple in case of variable length encodings (Unicode).